# How can I retrieve the device owner/user name?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a game/app where I aim to identify the current user without directly asking for their name. Instead, I want to retrieve their name from the Android system. I'm uncertain about the potential sources, but two possibilities come to mind:

1. The user's self-entered name in their contacts.
2. The registered name in the Android OS, especially during the initial boot if available.

Rest assured, I'm not using this information for any misleading purposes; it's purely for the game's functionality. At a certain point in the game, I plan to reveal their name within the app itself. Could someone please assist me with this?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify

Comment: the problem is if i use any kind of sign despite google facebook or manual , user will know that i have there names in the app , so revealing there names will not effect much as if i take no data from them and then reveal it , you can look something similar here with this game https://pixeldough.itch.io/start-survey for windows where it takes username from  C:/Users:/<CurrentUser>, thought it is also not accurate , as people can put any name for the user name,so sometimes it just dosent make sense, but i neither have an option too

Comment: Privacy is a big deal in Android. Apps have very limited access to sensitive information and almost always after requesting a permission.